# How to get multiple level factory for database seeding to work

Tags: php, laravel-5

So i'm trying to get factories setup to allow for random seeding of a test database. I want to be able to have a bunch of users created, who then create a bunch of rooms, and then post comments to the rooms.

This is what I have:

```
factory('App\User', 5)->create()->each(function($u) {
    $u->rooms()->save(factory('App\Room', 10)->create()->each(function($p) {
        $p->posts()->save(factory('App\Post', 10)->make());
    }));
});
```

I get the following error:

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given
```

I assume that the error means that it's not creating the rooms before it tries to create the posts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps a bit late, but you have to call **saveMany(...)** instead of **save(...)**
as described in the [Eloquent documentation](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.html#method_saveMany)

Indeed, you want to create more than one object (`factory('App\Room', 10)->create()` or `factory('App\Post', 10)->make()`), which return a Collection (in short words, an array of objects)

A special thank to a friend, who reminds me to RTM ^^

Comment: You may be a bit late, but you still help others! "Better late than never", and in my case, VERY MUCH SO! Thanks!